# Java SQL Unique username

Tags: java, mysql, database

Blank database.

If I enter a username example1 it will add to the database. Then if I try and re-add it again it will be stopped by my code as it already in the database. Then if I enter example2 and add it it will go into the database and then if I try and re-add it my code lets it go through the only thing that stops it is the database primary key:

I believe this line to be the issue:

```
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Members order by username asc");
```

Here is the whole method:

```
public static boolean CheckUsernameExists(String username){

    boolean usernameExists = false;

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB, usernameDB, passwordDB);

        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Members order by username asc");
        ResultSet r1=st.executeQuery();
        String usernameCounter;
        if(r1.next()){
            usernameCounter =  r1.getString("username");
            if(usernameCounter.equals(username)){
                System.out.println(username);
                usernameExists = true;
            }
        }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
     }catch (ClassNotFoundException cE){
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
     }

    return usernameExists;
}
```

Comment: This is insane. Get the database to search, rather than returning the *entire list of users*. Also, you can go an extra step and make the username unique in the database and you don't need to do any of this.

Comment: username is unique in database. The code makes it so I can alert the user to whats going on. Make an answer if you can help with how to get the database to search

Comment: Attempting to add a user with a duplicate username will throw an exception. You can catch this and provide appropriate feedback. As for searching on the DB, use `WHERE`.

Comment: I was under the impression catching exceptions was best for finding bugs etc?

Comment: Generally yes, but catching data integrity issues is also a good use (it means you can run a single query in place of two). Of course, you could also write super-convoluted SQL to handle it internally and produce a different output, but it would almost certainly be slower that way.

Comment: Also don't forget race conditions; finding that a username is available, then another request creating that user, then attempting to create the user will lead to an exception anyway. Might as well base the logic on the exception itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be better like this:

```
    PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Members where username = ? ");
    st.setString(1, username);
    ResultSet r1=st.executeQuery();
    if(r1.next()){
         System.out.println('user already exist in database!");
    }
    else{
        //Add to database
    }
```

Or since your method is `CheckUsernameExists`:

```
public static boolean CheckUsernameExists(String username){

    boolean usernameExists = false;
    try{
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Members where username = ? ");
        st.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet r1=st.executeQuery();
        if(r1.next()){
           usernameExists = true;
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
    }
    return usernameExists;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't iterate over all of the users. Just try and select the requierd username from the database. Also, if you use the provided string you are in danger of SQL Injection. Try and use this:

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Members where username = ?");
st.setString(1, username);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using this:

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select id from Members where username = ? ");
    //I assumed that their is id column in Members.
    st.setString(1, username);
    ResultSet resultSet=st.executeQuery();
    if(resultSet.next()){
         // prompt users already exists
    }
    else{
        //add to database
    }
```

Just grab a column that represent the row given, it really doesn't matter cause you just checking if there is a row that has username given by the user. (base on you current specs).

Answer (score -1):

Change your query to something like this:

```
"select * from Members where username=" +  username
```

It will return you only this user, there is no point on requesting all users from the database and then filter them on the application. You overload both the application and the database.

Comment: Use prepared statements and `?`. **NEVER** put user-supplied data into a query directly, or little bobby tables will play with your data. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Good example of SQL injection vulnerability